# 'post' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting errors in this component.ts file at push(post).
the error is 'post' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { post } from './comp/list/list.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
spost:post[]=[];

onpostadd(){
  this.spost.push(post);
}
}
```

this is the model.ts file

```
export interface post {

  title: string;
  content : string;

}
```

Comment: Well, it is a type. And you're using it as a value. So the error message is right. I've no idea what you are trying to achieve though.

Comment: because `post` is a type. What value do you want to push?

Comment: didn't getting it can you make it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is exactly as it says: You're only exporting an interface (which is just a type) `post`, not an actual value. Therefore you can't use it as a value.

Your `onpostadd()` probably expects `post` as an argument that you didn't add.

Also, it's quite common to CamelCase type names, similar to classes, e.g. use `Post` instead. This makes it hard to confuse it with lowercase variable names.

Comment: didn't getting it can you make it correct

Comment: I don't know your code or intentions well enough to know how to fix it. Your `onpostadd` is trying to push `post` to your array, but the `post` there is the type you imported, not an actual post from wherever. I assume you meant to write `onpostadd(post) { ... }`